# How to format YAML to include bracket as one of the value without quotes

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

I am using python3 yaml package to write yaml from dictionary like:

```
main1:
  aa:
    val1: [ ]
  bb:
  - val2: xxxxxxx
    val3: [1]
```

But am not able to get above.
All am getting:

```
main1:
  aa:
    val1: '[ ]'
  bb:
  - val2: xxxxxxx
    val3: '[1]'
```

My code snippet:

```
yaml.dump_all(data, f, default_flow_style=False, sort_keys=False)
```

**All I want is to remove single quotes around list element** keeping others as same as mentioned abaove, I have searched in various blogs and stack overflow answer nothing is working for me, any help?
I used  `yaml.dump(data,f, default_flow_style=None, sort_keys=False)` for dictionary :

```
data = {
    'main1': {
        'aa': {
            'val1': [],
            'check1':{'check2':1}
        },
        'bb': [{
          'val2': 'xxxxxxx',
          'val3': [1],
        }],
    },
}
```

It will work as expected for bracket, but nested dictionary format is not as expected.

```
main1:
  aa:
    val1: []
    check1: {check2: 1}
  bb:
  - val2: xxxxxxx
    val3: [1]
```

Expected:

```
main1:
  aa:
    val1: []
    check1: 
        check2: 1
  bb:
   - val2: xxxxxxx
     val3: [1]
```

Comment: Not a solution but workaround, I can achieve this by opening file as a text mode and than apply regex and write again as a yaml. f = open("1.yaml", "r")
t = f.read()
import re
print(t)
tmp = re.sub("'\[", "[", t)
print(t)
f = open("2.yaml", "w")
f.write(tmp)
f.close()

Comment: It's not possible to tell a YAML processor to remove the quotes because the `[]` brackets are a syntax element in YAML. You also wouldn't expect you can do this when writing a file in JSON format, right?

Comment: @ruohola I think I understand pretty well. `'[1]'` is a string of 3 characters in YAML, while `[1]` is a sequence with one item, the number 1, written in the compact [flow style](https://www.yaml.info/learn/flowstyle.html). I'm member of the YAML core team and author of the linked tutorial.

Comment: @ShubhamChauhan please create a [mcve]. Your question is missing the python code you are using.

Comment: @tinita ... Too little coffee today. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

The following code returns the output you want for me (except the missing space between the `[` and `]` in line 3):

```py
import yaml

data = {
    'main1': {
        'aa': {
            'val1': []
        },
        'bb': [{
          'val2': 'xxxxxxx',
          'val3': [1],
        }],
    },
}

print(yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=None, sort_keys=False))
```

Output:

```yaml
main1:
  aa:
    val1: []
  bb:
  - val2: xxxxxxx
    val3: [1]
```

You didn't show how you create the data dictionary, so I'm just guessing here.

Comment: You added a second example for data and a second output, but it's not clear what your expected output is. It works like intended. If `default_flow_style` is set to `None`, then dictionaries and lists which don't have nested dictionaries and lists are dumped in flow style. It's not possible to customize this further with pyyaml.